# Solutions of a differential equation from Elsgolts "Differential Equations and Variational calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation from Elsgolts's book:
$y'=y^{2} + \frac{y}{1+x}$
I noticed that the equation can be re-written in the form $-\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1+x}{y})=1+x$. Thus, integrating we get $y=-\frac{2(1+x)}{x^2+2x+c}$, while the book says the correct solution is $y=\frac{2(1+x)}{x^2+2x+c}$  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

$$-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1+x}{y}=1+x \implies \frac{(1+x)y'-y}{y^2}=1+x \implies (1+x)y'=y+y^2(1+x)$$
$$\implies y'=y^2+\frac{y}{1+x}.$$

The OP is rifght.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there's a sign mistake in the second passage, you're supposed to derive first the function at the numerator

Comment: Oh! you are right. I have corrected it now.

Comment: So, is my solution correct? Cause then you get the same result as mine. I think this may be a typographic error of the book

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Perfect, thank you